# Alloy UI - editing an event with values selected (in selectlist)

Tags: javascript, calendar, alloy-ui

I might have gone a wrong way around this but I have managed to get 2 selectlist options visible on my calendar popup and am able to save the data to the DB.

Where I am struggling now is when clicking an event to edit, how can I pass back in the values so that the selectlist shows the current values. To go with this, how can I pass in the database Id assigned to this event too?

I have shown my code so far below:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<script>
    YUI({ debug: true, combine: false }).use(
        'aui-scheduler',
            function(Y) 
            {
                                var events = [
                                        {
                        id: '',
                        color: '#d2e04f',
                        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
                        titleDateFormat: '',
                        content: 'Available<br />EARLY', 
                        endDate: new Date(2017, 09, 20), 
                        startDate: new Date(2017, 09, 16)
                    },
                                        {
                        id: '',
                        color: '#d2e04f',
                        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
                        titleDateFormat: '',
                        content: 'Available<br />ALL DAY', 
                        endDate: new Date(2017, 09, 02), 
                        startDate: new Date(2017, 09, 02)
                    },
                                        {
                        id: '',
                        color: '#d2e04f',
                        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
                        titleDateFormat: '',
                        content: 'Available<br />', 
                        endDate: new Date(2017, 09, 03), 
                        startDate: new Date(2017, 09, 03)
                    },
                                        {
                        id: '',
                        color: '#d2e04f',
                        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
                        titleDateFormat: '',
                        content: 'Available<br />', 
                        endDate: new Date(2017, 09, 03), 
                        startDate: new Date(2017, 09, 03)
                    }
                                    ];

                var monthView = new Y.SchedulerMonthView({ isoTime: true });
                var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
                    on: {
                        save: function(event) {
                            //alert('Save Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode() + ' --- ' + this.getClearStartDate() + ' --- ' + this.getClearEndDate());
                            var data = this.serializeForm();
                            console.log(data);
                            var ds = new Date(data.startDate);
                            var de = new Date(data.endDate);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/candidates/availability/2830b9d7cf',
                                data:  { 'do': 'availability-save', 'booking_status': data.booking_status, 'shift_type': data.shift_type, 'date_start': ds.getFullYear() + '-' + (ds.getMonth()+1) + '-' + ds.getDate(), 'date_end': de.getFullYear() + '/' + (de.getMonth()+1) + '/' + de.getDate() },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        edit: function(event) {
                            //alert('Edit Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode() + ' --- ' + this.getClearStartDate() + ' --- ' + this.getClearEndDate());
                            var data = this.serializeForm();
                            console.log(data);
                            var ds = new Date(data.startDate);
                            var de = new Date(data.endDate);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/candidates/availability/2830b9d7cf',
                                data:  { 'do': 'availability-edit', 'booking_status': data.booking_status, 'shift_type': data.shift_type, 'date_start': ds.getFullYear() + '-' + (ds.getMonth()+1) + '-' + ds.getDate(), 'date_end': de.getFullYear() + '/' + (de.getMonth()+1) + '/' + de.getDate() },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        delete: function(event) {
                            //alert('Delete Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode() + ' --- ' + this.getClearStartDate() + ' --- ' + this.getClearEndDate());
                            var data = this.serializeForm();
                            console.log(data);
                            var ds = new Date(data.startDate);
                            var de = new Date(data.endDate);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/candidates/availability/2830b9d7cf',
                                data:  { 'do': 'availability-delete', 'booking_status': data.booking_status, 'shift_type': data.shift_type, 'date_start': ds.getFullYear() + '-' + (ds.getMonth()+1) + '-' + ds.getDate(), 'date_end': de.getFullYear() + '/' + (de.getMonth()+1) + '/' + de.getDate() },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 
                    dateFormat: '%a, %b %d, %Y',
                    //content: '',
                    repeated: true,
                    headerTemplate: '<select name="booking_status"><option value="5">Available</option><option value="6">Unavailable</option></select><br /><select name="shift_type"><option>Not Required</option><option>ALL DAY</option><option>LONG DAY</option><option>EARLY</option><option>LATE</option><option>NIGHT</option><option>TWILIGHT</option></select>',
                    clientId: '2830b9d7cf'
                });

                new Y.Scheduler(
                  {
                    activeView: monthView,
                    boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
                    date: new Date(2017, 09, 13),
                    eventRecorder: eventRecorder,
                    items: events,
                    render: true,
                    views: [monthView], 
                    firstDayOfWeek: 1
                  }
                );
            }
    );
</script>
```

thanks in advance,

Raj

Comment: It might be helpful if you separate out the JS and PHP code and simply provide JS code with example dummy data that would have come from  PHP. That way we could more easily see what you are trying to do and test it in the browser outside of a PHP environment.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 - code updated for you. thanks

Comment: @PHPology did you manage to work out how to do this?

Comment: @Shazoo - nope, used FullCalendar instead :-)